Combined USB-C/Thunderbolt/Displayport port: can I see which connection is active?
I have a Windows laptop with a combined USB-C/Thunderbolt 3/Displayport port.
I'm trying to troubleshoot problems I have when connecting it to various docking stations: some docking stations allow higher resolutions on the same monitors than other docking stations.
Is there a way to see which connection is being used when I connect the dock to this port? Currently I'm guessing, based on incomplete specifications of the docking stations I've tried.
Scores so far:

Startech USB3DOCKH2DP: USB, DisplayLink: 2 monitors at 2560x1440 each
Dell TB19: according to the dock specs, should be Thunderbolt, 2 monitors at 2560x1440 each
AVAccess iDock C20: USB-C MST, 1 monitor at 2560x1440 and one at 1920x1080.


This is a highly complex topic. Check my answer on a related question. You can check out my favorite Video Timings calculator here.
